# How can I extract lands from a colored map?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm getting trouble extracting the lands from this game map.

[image: map of middle-earth]

The answer will actually be 8 images, which represent the countries of this continent. This map (continent) is actually a part of a bigger game map that I already decomposed into several images. Each of them represents a continent with a different color.

I tried HSV segmentation, threshold and watershed algorithm and they didn't work optimally. The image is still noisy and the land areas are cut off.

Could anyone suggest any alternative methods? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of segmenting the yellow color, you should try segmenting the black color and the invert the mask.

Comment: It's not really simple. If you do not need to do it on hundreds of images, I would consider repaint the borders in some color (e.g. red) that's not yet existing on the images and work from there. What you basically have to differentiate is the border lines from the rest of the decorations in the map. However, it's a really good question. Thanks for posting it.

Comment: What will the answer be? Is it an image where all the black is now transparent? Or will it be 12 images with one country in each image? Something else?

Comment: The answer will actually be 8 images, which represent the countries of this continent. This map (continent) is actually a part of a bigger game map that I already decomposed into several images. Each of them represents a continent with a different color.

Comment: “I tried HSV segmentation, threshold and watershed algorithm and they didn't work optimally.” Instead of *saying* what you did, *show* what you did. That is, post your code. Show why it does not do what you want it to do. You will get much more useful answers if you do that. See [ask].

Comment: Also, [edit] your question to clarify it, don’t post clarifying notes in the comments, they can disappear at any moment leaving your question incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is quite a challenge. I present the simple approach which nevertheless only delivers a crude approximation.

1. convert rgb image to grayscale
2. apply threshold to obtain black-and-white image
3. fill holes (the background pixels that cannot be reached from outside)
4. label the areas and filter those with an area below a threshold

In did it in Matlab

```
im = imread('FyrNE.jpg');
I = rgb2gray(im);
[L, n] = bwlabel(bwareafilt(I>160,[1e2,Inf]));
imagesc(imfill(L, 'holes'))
```

This is the result with 12 detected countries, which is still sub-optimal.

[image]

What you really want to do is either employ more fancy algorithms detecting smooth curves of a certain length (the border curves), or, if the task doesn't need to be done repeatedly, repaint the borders manually with a distinguishable color (e.g. red) and start from there.